# How to combine a QueryStringQuery via a BoolQuery with an arbitrary other query in ElasticSearch, using the Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch at version 0.90.5.
I'm trying to restrict my query, that has been parsed using the QueryStringQuery, with a GeoShapeQuery like that:

```
public SearchResponse search(final String queryString, final Rectangle bbox){
    final QueryBuilder queryA = QueryBuilders.queryString(queryString);
    final QueryBuilder queryB = QueryBuilders.geoShapeQuery(GEO_FIELD_NAME, bbox);
    final QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                              .must(queryA)
                                              .must(queryB);
    return client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
                 .setQuery(query)
                 ...
}
```

But when it the query is meant to build, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilderException: Failed to build query
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BaseQueryBuilder.toString(BaseQueryBuilder.java:42)
at org.bitmash.data.EsDatabase.search(EsDatabase.java:279)
at org.agopt.server.GisServer.search(GisServer.java:270)
at org.bitmash.gis.protocol.requests.SearchRequest.process(SearchRequest.java:40)
at org.bitmash.gis.protocol.requests.SearchRequest.process(SearchRequest.java:21)
at network.tcp.binary.BinaryServerSide$1.run(BinaryServerSide.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Current context not an ARRAY but OBJECT
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase._reportError(GeneratorBase.java:444)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeEndArray(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:229)
at  org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.writeEndArray(JsonXContentGenerator.java:59)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.endArray(XContentBuilder.java:227)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.doXArrayContent(BoolQueryBuilder.java:182)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.doXContent(BoolQueryBuilder.java:149)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BaseQueryBuilder.toXContent(BaseQueryBuilder.java:65)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BaseQueryBuilder.toString(BaseQueryBuilder.java:39)
... 8 more
```

Am I missing something?
Is it possible at all, to combine any two queries using the BoolQuery?

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: You are doing it right, but there seems to be a problem when generating the json query. What is the Rectangle class you have in your code?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: The Rectangle class refers to `com.spatial4j.core.shape.Rectangle`. See also [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html) for the example I got this from.

Comment: maybe I found the problem's origin: [Fix toXContent of GeoShapeQueryBuilder](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/3887). But since I'm out of the office, it will take a few days to check that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, yeah sounds like that is the fix. If you still have the same problem do open an issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed, that the problem originated from the following issue:

[Fix toXContent of GeoShapeQueryBuilder #3887](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/3887)

After updating my ElasticSearch installation, everything worked fine.